# Error al intentar acceder a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Escribo esta pregunta a raíz de un problema que tengo en una aplicación Python. En dicha app, tengo 3 métodos que, leyendo un archivo .csv, muestran las filas de los últimos 7, 30 y 365 días.
Mi problema es que, en el método de los últimos 365 días, me lanza una excepción "Key Error: 0" al declarar una variable x para recorrer el DataFrame que recorre el csv. En los otros 2 métodos no me saca ninguna excepción.
Adjunto el código de los 3 métodos debajo:

```
def GrafUlt7Dias():
    hist_csv = pd.read_csv('Historicos.csv')

    time = "HostTimestamp (ms)"
    temp = "Temperature (℃)"
    hum = "Humidity (%)"
    date = "Date"

    df_hist = pd.DataFrame(hist_csv, columns = [date, time, temp, hum])

    x = df_hist.first_valid_index()
    fecha = datetime.strptime(df_hist[date][df_hist.last_valid_index()], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    fechaUlt7 = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    if fecha >= fechaUlt7:
        df_ult7 = pd.DataFrame(df_hist)
        for i in range(0, len(df_hist)):
            df_ult7.insert(df_hist[x])
            x += 1

        df_ult7.plot(x = time, y = [temp, hum], figsize = (9, 5))
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
    else:
        popup = Popup(title = 'Alerta', content = Label(text = 'Sin registros en los últimos 7 días'),
        size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()

def GrafUlt30Dias():
    hist_csv = pd.read_csv('Historicos.csv')

    time = "HostTimestamp (ms)"
    temp = "Temperature (℃)"
    hum = "Humidity (%)"
    date = "Date"

    df_hist = pd.DataFrame(hist_csv, columns = [date, time, temp, hum])

    x = df_hist.first_valid_index()
    fecha = datetime.strptime(df_hist[date][df_hist.last_valid_index()], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    fechaUlt30 = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
    if fecha >= fechaUlt30:
        df_ult7 = pd.DataFrame(df_hist)
        for i in range(0, len(df_hist)):
            df_ult7.insert(df_hist[x])
            x += 1

        df_ult7.plot(x = time, y = [temp, hum], figsize = (9, 5))
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
    else:
        popup = Popup(title = 'Alerta', content = Label(text = 'Sin registros en los últimos 30 días'),
        size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()

def GrafUlt365Dias():
    hist_csv = pd.read_csv('Historicos.csv')

    time = "HostTimestamp (ms)"
    temp = "Temperature (℃)"
    hum = "Humidity (%)"
    date = "Date"

    df_hist = pd.DataFrame(hist_csv, columns = [date, time, temp, hum])
    x = df_hist.first_valid_index()
    fecha = datetime.strptime(df_hist[date][df_hist.last_valid_index()], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    fechaUlt365 = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
    if fecha >= fechaUlt365:
        df_ult365 = pd.DataFrame(df_hist)
        for i in range(0, len(df_hist)):
            df_ult365.insert(df_hist[x])
            x += 1

        df_ult365.plot(x = time, y = [temp, hum], figsize = (9, 5))
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
    else:
        popup = Popup(title = 'Alerta', content = Label(text = 'Sin registros en los últimos 365 días'),
        size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()
```

¿Alguien sabe de dónde podría venir el error?
Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask].  Por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto con las que se pueda reproducir el problema, también agrega el error completo que te aparece.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `df_hist[x]` por `df_hist.loc[x]`

Comment: El problema es que en los dos métodos anteriores sí que funciona correctamente. El único en que da error es GrafUlt365Dias()